# Глобальный фиксированный порядок блокировок

Tags: многопоточность, теория

Как работает задание блокировкам глобального фиксированного порядка? Для чего это нужно?

Comment: Объясните мне, пожалуйста, при чем тут java и c#? В других языках, что, не существует проблемы взаимоблокировок?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как правильный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Примеры кода предпочтительны на C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это способ избежать взаимоблокировок (deadlocks).

Работает он просто: всем ресурсам присваиваются уникальные номера. Блокировать ресурсы каждому потоку разрешается только в порядке увеличения номера, снятие блокировки, соответственно, происходит в порядке уменьшения.

Полезнее всего данный метод оказывается в ситуациях, когда все ресурсы, для которых понадобится взять блокировку, оказываются известны заранее. Так, в [задаче об обедающих философах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2) можно пронумеровать вилки и заставить философов брать вилки в порядке возрастания. Аналогичное решение применимо в задаче о банковских счетах и переводах между ними.

Comment: Непонятно как при задании уникальных номеров избегаются взаимоблокировки. Можете пояснить?